# How do I keep the value of a FileField after submission?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

My app looks as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import IntegerField, FileField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret'

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    myFile = FileField('File')
    myInt = IntegerField('Number')

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def home():
    form = MyForm()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', form=form)
    else:
        myFile = form.myFile
        myInt = form.myInt
        print("The file is {} and the int is {}".format(myFile.data, myInt.data))
        return render_template('index.html', form=form)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True)
```

and my HTML file is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ form.myFile.label }} {{ form.myFile }}<br>
        {{ form.myInt.label }} {{ form.myInt }}<br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I select a file, enter a 4 in the IntegerField and press Submit, I get the following print:

```
The file is <FileStorage: 'file.txt' ('text/plain')> and the int is 4
```

After the page reloads, I still see the 4 I entered, but I no longer see the name of the file next to the Browse button. Unsurprisingly, if I click Submit again, I get:

```
The file is <FileStorage: '' ('application/octet-stream')> and the int is 4
```

How can I pass on the file name after hitting the button? Even if it's not displayed to the user, I would like the value to remain stored in the form.

I know I can save the file, but I would like to avoid that, and I don't understand why `FileField`'s behavior is so different from that of `IntegerField`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44119600/how-to-keep-input-after-failed-form-validation-in-flask

Comment: @Gasp0de I had found that question and that solution is what I included in my example, in particular the `return render_template('index.html', form=form)`. As I wrote, it works for all fields of the form **except** for `FileFields`. In the answer you linked, the only fields in the form are strings, and I don't have a problem with those.

Comment: I am sorry, I was mistaken. Apparently it is not possible to pre-populate the FileField: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67637364/how-to-pre-populate-wtform-filefield-with-current-image-file-name. If you think about it, browsers should probably forbid this behaviour anyway. Imagine someone goes to your site and the field is pre-filled by you with the path "/path/to/passwordfile.txt", then they click "Send" and you have their password file. I think it is good that they always have to explicitely select a file.